# Grab ALL values from a column pulled out of a DB comma seperated and put into a textfield

Tags: javascript, php, html, mysql

I have a table which contains the column fleet name, vehicle registration and some other info about each vehicle. 1 fleet can have many vehicles. The main aim of my application is to show vehicles within a fleet when a fleet is selected (from a dropdown), so filtering out and showing rows of the database (based on the column "fleet_name") so the results show only the cars in the selected fleet (this is already achieved, see code below). what i'm now trying to achieve is to grab, with a click of a button, ALL of the pulled out phone numbers of the vehicles within the selected fleet, comma seperated, so if the fleet had 3 vehicles, once you click the "grab numbers" button you would get 074123456789,07412347321,074292839201 in the textfield. if the 0 in the beggining could be changed to 44, that would be a huge bonus too! so i've got as far as being able to grab a row's phone number singular:

currently my code to show all the data:

```
<?php

$sql = "SELECT * FROM main_table";
if (isset($_POST['search'])) {
$search_term = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['search_box']);
$sql .= " WHERE fleet_name='$search_term'";
$sql .= " OR vehicle_registration_number='$search_term'";
}
$query = mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());
?>
```

form which filters out the data:

```
<form name="search_form" method="POST" action="index2.php">

<?php $sql2 = "SELECT DISTINCT fleet_name FROM main_table"; 
$query2 = mysql_query($sql2); 
echo "<p> Select Fleet Name: <select name='search_box'><option></option>";
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query2)){ echo "<option>{$row['fleet_name']}</option>"; } 
echo "</select></p>"; ?>
<input type="submit" name="search" value="Search the table...">

</form>
```

and my table code:

```
<table width="70%" cellpadding="5" cellspacing="5">

<tr>
<td><strong>Fleet Name</strong></td>
<td><strong>SIM Mobile Number</strong></td>
</tr>
<?php while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($query)) { ?>
<td><?php echo $row['fleet_name']; ?></td>
<td><?php echo $row['mobile_number']; ?><input type="button" value="select"   onclick="clickMe('<?php echo $row['mobile_number']; ?>')" /></td>
<tr>
```

my button code atm:

```
function clickMe(number) {
     $("#textfield").val(number);
}
```

and my textfield code:

```
  <input type="text" name="to" id="textfield">
```

Thank you so much for taking time to read this and any help given.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use the

```
GROUP_CONCAT(COLUMN_NAME)
```

this will give the comma separated value of your column values.

Comment: Thanks for your help, i've got as far as:   
    $sql = "SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(sim_mobile_number) FROM   main_table";
    $query = mysql_query($sql);
    $row = mysql_fetch_array($query); 
    $allnum = $row["sim_mobile_number"];
--------------------------------------------------------
<input type="submit" value="all" name="getAllNumbers" />
<input type="text" value="<? echo $allnum; ?>"/>
is the query correct? if so, how do I output the values from the submit button into the textfield?

Answer (score 0):

You can use PHP [implode()](http://php.net/function.implode) function.